# Android: CalendarView onDateChangelistener Milliseconds value to DatePicker Milliseconds value

Tags: android

I can't seem to correctly compare the two milleseconds value from teh CalendarView using `cw.getDate()` method

and the Calendars c.set() and c.getTimeInMillis inside the OnDateListner of The DatePicker

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dateView.setText(formatDate(c.getTimeInMillis()));
        dateViewMilli.setText(Long.toString(c.getTimeInMillis()));
    }
};
```

Here is the picture for difference

[image]

[image]

So how do i get the Milliseconds in DatePicker wherein it is completely the same value in CalendarView?.. cuz i can't query perfectly the values of the two cuz they have different long value.. i mean both timestamp are different despite it having same day, month, year... dunno wat happend.. maybe its on the parsing or wat.. for those any of you who have some knowledge about this please do share

UPDATE

---

I have just read some article, and a friend also told me that both produces different timestamp values, thus best thing to do is to fomrat the timestamp first, say MM/DD/YYYY, then store is as a string den that's the time you compare..

Any other inputs are welcome also...

Comment: Have you any solution to press same value in CalendarView?

Comment: do u have the same problem?, i just read something about producing different time stamp, so some say best thing to do is to format it and store it as a string den u compare the strings